# Is there a way to make the Start Time closer than Schedule Time in an SCOM Task?

Tags: powershell, sccm, sccm-2007

I realize that when I execute a SCOM Task on demand from a Powershell script, there are 2 columns in Task Status view called `Schedule Time` and `Start Time`. It seems that there is an interval these two fields of around 15 seconds. I'm wondering if there is a way to minimize this time so I could have a response time shorter when I execute an SCOM task on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not generally something that users can control.  The "ScheduledTime" correlates to the time when the SDK received the request to execute the task.  The "StartTime" represents the time that the agent healthservice actually began executing the task workflow locally.

In between those times, things are moving as fast as they can.  The request needs to propagate to the database, and a server healthservice needs to be notified that a task is being triggered.  The servers then need to determine the correct route for the task message to take, then the healthservices need to actually send and receive the message.  Finally, it gets to the actual agent where the task will execute.  All of these messages go through the same queues as other monitoring data.

That sequence can be very quick (when running a task against the local server), or fairly slow (in a big Management Group, or when there is lots of load, or if machines/network are slow).  Besides upgrading your hardware, you can't really do anything to make the process run quicker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, makes sense for me. I'll try to test my MP in a better hardware environment.